# How do I program an Error message if the user presses enter without putting a number in. (e.g. putting a letter or nothing at all)

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

```
 'the variables
        Dim watertemp As Decimal 'changed variable to decimal so that decimal numbers can be input.
        Dim fahren As Decimal
        Dim newtemp As String


        'this code asks the intial question (the temp of the water)
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the tempurature of the water, between -273.15 and 100 degrees celcius.")
        watertemp = Console.ReadLine





        'this code is to work out what the water should be called and the colour of the text it will be displayed in.
        If watertemp <= 0 Then
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue
            Console.WriteLine("The water is freezing")
        End If
        If watertemp >= 1 And watertemp <= 25 Then
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan
            Console.WriteLine("The water is warm")
        End If
        If watertemp >= 26 And watertemp <= 60 Then
            Console.WriteLine("The water is hot")
        End If
        If watertemp >= 61 And watertemp <= 99 Then
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta
            Console.WriteLine("The water is very hot")
        End If
        If watertemp >= 100 Then
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
            Console.WriteLine("The water is boiling")
        End If

        'this code converts the tempurature to fahrenheit
        fahren = (9 / 5 * watertemp) + 32
        Console.WriteLine("The water is " & (Format(fahren, "0.00")) & " °F")

        'this code changes the text back to white
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
        'this code asks the user if they would like to convert another input
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to convert another tempurature?")
        newtemp = Console.ReadLine

        'this code determines whether to carry on with converting another input or end the program
        If newtemp = "no" Then
            Console.WriteLine("This is the end of the program")
        End If
        If newtemp = "yes" Then
            Console.WriteLine("What is the tempurature of the water?")
            watertemp = Console.ReadLine
        End If
        fahren = (9 / 5 * watertemp) + 32
        Console.WriteLine("The water is " & (Format(fahren, "0.00")) & " °F")

        Console.ReadLine()
```

I need to have an error message if the user inputs something that the program cannot run, such as letters or nothing at all.

I tried a few things but I dont know if I did any of them right as I am very new to coding.

Comment: If String.IsNullOrEmpty(watertemp) Then.... should be the test, then report the feedback to the users.  What happens there is up to you as there a plenty of options.  Maybe you want to loop until the enter a value, or abort the execution, or build in exception handling.  BTW, you probably want to read up on Set Option Strict.  You've got some implied type casting going on there that might give you problems

Comment: The first thing you should do is turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties. You should also set it `On` in the VS options, so it is `On` by default in all future projects. Code like this will then fail to compile: `watertemp = Console.ReadLine`. That is assigning a `string` to a variable of type `decimal`, which requires a widening conversion. All widening conversions must be explicit with `Option Strict On`. Had you done the research you should have, you'd know that `decimal.TryParse` will validate your input and convert it if it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim watertemp As Decimal 'changed variable to decimal so that decimal numbers can be input.
Dim fahren As Decimal
Dim newtemp As String

reenter:
        'this code asks the intial question (the temp of the water)
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the tempurature of the water, between -273.15 and 100 degrees celcius.")
        watertemp = Console.ReadLine
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(watertemp) OrElse Not IsNumeric(watertemp) Then
            MsgBox("Wrong input.")
            GoTo reenter
        End If
```